# How to, with 'get template part', select a file that's two folders deep in WP?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building WordPress site.

I'm trying to do this

```
get_template_part( 'templates/blocks/section-header-page.php' );
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
-mainFOlder
--assets

--templates
---blocks {
----section-header-page.php
----section-contact.php
}
```

How do I access the files in that folder? With get template part.

Comment: That should work.  We need more context - where are you trying to call this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_template_part()` takes two parameters the first is the $slug or location of the template and slug. The second the name of the actual template.

get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null );

So in your case this should work.

```
get_template_part( 'templates/blocks/section' , 'header-page' );

get_template_part( 'templates/blocks/section', 'contact');
```

Can't confirm, I have not tested it.

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work. I tried many combinations. Well, so far, I removed the 'blocks' folder, and it works. On other places it read that WP can't go two folders deep, which seems strange to me.

Comment: Get template ultimately calls locate_template you could just call that with the path

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get rid of the ".php" on your template string.
Wordpress automatically assumes it's a php file so no extension is needed.

```html
get_template_part( 'templates/blocks/section-header-page' );
```